# Changing drainage from washing machine

Tags: drainage, drains

I have a new build house that has a drainage on the side of the house as shown in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BU_-fnvqCOI

I want to change this so that it does not drain on the side of the house like this but rather to the city drain system (i'm in Toronto).

How big a job would this be? Any advice or direction? Thank you

Comment: They allow that for new builds!?  It doesn't make any sense to build a new house that way, especially in freeze territory where it will accumulate into a pile of ice.  Might check with the city building inspector and see if that's legit.  That stuff is **graywater**, which generally needs special treatment... *dark* gray as it'll have fecal matter in it when "accident" clothing is washed.

Comment: OH WOW.. really.... Is your laundy anywhere near a drain line?

Comment: We can not  answer this with out knowing were all the plumbing is in your house. You need to know how close the laundry room is in relation to the nearest drain, (bathroom, kitchen etc) and if there is an unobstructed path to get to that drain system. why do want to change it?   if you use eco friendly bio degradable soaps and if you do not wash you " harpers accidents" clothing then you are not causing harm to the environment ( if that is your only concern)